# What to put in MediaWiki User Specific common.js

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I was just invited onto a wiki that utilizes MediaWiki and I want to get my `common.js` up and running.

Basically I want to set up a js file that runs when people visit my page. This is possible in MediaWiki by utilizing a file in the wiki called `User:ExampleUsername/common.js` as shown [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript#User-specific). I do not have administrative privileges so I cannot edit `MediaWiki:common.js`. This is why I must take the `User:ExampleUsername/common.js` route.

This page `User:ExampleUsername/common.js` is not made yet on the wiki. I plan to make it.

Once it is made *what goes in it? Is is simply a js file that is run on the visit of my page?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I want to set up a js file that runs when people visit my page.

This isn't possible. If it were, it would be considered a huge security vulnerability.

Your user script page, `User:Username/common.js`, is only loaded *for you* when you are logged into the wiki. It does not affect any other users.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay thank you for clearing this up. In that case, what can I put into User:Username/common.js? I put alert("welcome") but nothing happened. When will this JS be triggered? Is the reason why it is not triggered because $wgAllowUserJs is not set to true?

Comment: `$wgAllowUserJs` must indeed be set to true (it is false by default)